# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MetaTrader 5

Tags: python-3.x, metatrader5

I am trying to install a Python package, MetaTrader 5, using the command

```
python3 -m pip install MetaTrader5
```

And I have even tried

```
pip install MetaTrader5
```

But it throws the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MetaTrader5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for MetaTrader5
```

I am using:

- [Ubuntu 16.04.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus)
- Python 3.6.10

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

If you look at [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/MetaTrader5/) and view the [wheel](https://pypi.org/project/MetaTrader5/5.0.37/#files) files, you will see that all the builds are for Windows. `pip` is refusing to install, because it can't find a Mac or Linux version.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Mac. On it, I have [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) installed on macOS. In addition, I have a virtual machine running Windows, and I have also installed Conda on Windows. I could install the MetaTrader 5 package using [pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_%28package_manager%29) on the virtual machine, but not on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

Download Python version 3.10.0, and then try installing MetaTrader 5.

Get it from [this page](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3100/).

Comment: Care to explain why this would work? Did you found out that it doesn't work with other versions of Python? (I can't image that, but I'm not familiar with the MataTrader5 module.) And on Ubuntu, Python is generally not installed by downloading it from the Python website. Please provide additional details on why/how this solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[user19562646's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60724857/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-metatrader5/73005677#73005677) is the correct one.

The package is binary only, and the binaries are for Windows only.

I was able to install the Windows version of Python with [Wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29), and install this package.

Apparently, Wine emulates Windows 7, but the latest Python version requires Windows 8.1. The last Python version that supports Windows 7 was Python 3.8.10. I tried it with this version, but there was a Wine error about an unimplemented feature. (`wine: Unimplemented function api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll.fetestexcept`)

I have tried it with [Python 3.6.8](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-368/), and it seems to work with this one so far.

(Later Python versions that are older than 3.8.10 may work too, but I haven't tried.)

To run the **Python 3.6.8 Windows installer** with Wine:

```
wine python-3.6.8-amd64.exe
```

To install the MetaTrader 5 package:

```
wine /PATH_TO_PYTHON_3.6.8/python.exe -m pip install MetaTrader5
```

To run the app:

```
wine /PATH_TO_PYTHON_3.6.8/python.exe myapp.py
```

**Initializing the MetaTrader 5 module:**

I was able to run the `MetaTrader5.initialize ()` function successfully without any parameters, but it seemed to fail when called with parameters such as `path`. Without any parameters it finds and launches the MetaTrader 5 terminal successfully (that was also installed with Wine), and all the API functions also work.

Comment: Dear @petermortensen, please don't remove styling from my post. All styling was added as intended, in view of decades of experience in writing content. There was no overuse of styling, no misapplied styling, nor violation of policy here. **wine** is also an exact package name, it's fine to spell it in lower case. Note that **MetaTrader5** is also an exact package name and module name. This is technical documentation, referring to exact names is acceptable and intended. The intent of this site is to help others, in this spirit, I urge you to cut back on insignificant edits to posts of others.

Comment: @petermortensen , the edits with the addition of the links are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vKzDJVZ_bc), MetaTrader 5 currently doesn't support Ubuntu. It's only available on Windows.

Comment: MetaTrader5 is also a python package to interface with Metatrader 5 terminal. It is possible to run the terminal under Wine in Linux but  the package is not recognised under Linux unfortunately...

Comment: So does that mean there is no version available for MacOS either?

Answer (score 0):

I having been trying to install MetaTrader 5 on my [Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) laptop, but still it is not working. But I was able to run my MetaTrader 5 Python script through the MetaTrader 5 IDE.

To use Python through the MetaTrader 5 IDE, follow these steps:

- Open the MetaTrader 5 application on your laptop or desktop.
- Click on the 'IDE' button from the standard toolbar.
- In the MetaTrader 5 IDE, click on 'Create New Document.'
- From the pop-up window, select 'Python Script' and follow the prompts.

Answer (score -1):

MetaTrader 5 for Python only works with certain versions.

Install one of the versions below to make MetaTrader 5 work.

[image: screenshot listing Python versions for MetaTrader 5]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74888135/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK, the OP has probably [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than a month ago"*